# How to reshape a list to a array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Sorry if my question related to others

I have a list that generates as

```
my_list=[]
my_shape=[6,6,6,6,8]
for i in range (5):
    for j in range(3):
        vector=np.random.rand(1,my_shape[i])
        my_list.expend(vector)
```

The output is a list with the length of 96 `(=3*32)`. I want to reshape the matrix to the size of `3x32` that I find the solution likes

```
my_matrix = np.reshape(my_list,3,32)) #=6+6+6+6+8
```

However, I want the element in my matrix must follow the rules

- The first row of matrix are `[vector(i=0, j=0), vector(i=1, j=0), ..., vector (i=4,j=0)]` where `vector(i=0, j=0)` is vector in the i=0  and j=0 iterations.
- The second row of matrix are `[vector(i=0, j=1), vector(i=1, j=1), ..., vector (i=4,j=1)]`
- The third row of matrix are `[vector(i=0, j=2), vector(i=1, j=2), ..., vector (i=4,j=2)]`

And so on. I think the `np.reshape(my_list,3,32))` cannot give me expected result. How can I achieve my expected result? Note that, the `j` can be larger likes `100`, I just give a simple example with `j=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
np.reshape(my_list, (5, 3)).T
```

work for you?

Comment: I have checked. It is most simple answer that I expect. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Aguy: Your solution is not correct because the shape of vectors are not same. Let see the shape of last vector is 8 instead of 6

Comment: This is what you asked for. You asked for the last vector in the first row to be `vector(i=4,j=0)`. Since `my_shape[4]` is 8 you indeed get a vector of length 8.